# AHK - ControlSend not working

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to select my audio devices with AHK and right now I have something like this:

```
Run, mmsys.cpl
WinWait,Sound
ControlSend,SysListView321,{Down 1}
```

The first line works fine and the sound dialog appears but the ControlSend part doesn't seem to do anything. Does anyone have any idea why? I expect it to select the top entry by hitting the down key.. I'm running on Windows 10 if that helps at all.

Comment: could you try including a `Sleep` just after `Run, mmsys.cpl` to make sure it is waiting for the `Sound` window. The code works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Run, mmsys.cpl
Loop{
    IfWinExist Sound
    {
        ControlSend,SysListView321,{Down 1}
        break
    }
}
```

your code works for me, but for you i think the issue is with the WinWait. If it is, then the above mentioned code will work for you